# InDesign interchanged TOC levels

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

I have a really weird problem with my InDesign TOC – it interchanges the levels I preset in the Table of Contents menu.

The setup looks like that:
Included Paragraph Styles:
name – Level: 1, Page Number: No Page Number
h1 – Level: 2, Page Number: After Entry

When I create the TOC it changes interchanges the Levels like so:
h1 #
name

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A ToC does not change the order in which the marked styles appear in the document. Are you sure your document styles appear in the correct order in the text?

Comment: Wait a minute – are you trying to say that the TOC can only arrange the entries in the order in which they appear on the text?
Like: In every article  the headline is set before the name of the author and that means that it can only appear in that order in the TOC?

Comment: Uh yes. There is a 'sort' checkbox but I think that's to sort alphabetically only. The TOC generator goes through your stories and every time it encounters one of your styles, it adds it directly into the TOC. Which is "good enough" for a lot, but not nearly *all* kinds of Contents. I've found most need some (or a lot of) post processing.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out! What exactly are the levels in the menu for, then?

Comment: It's because your `h1` and your `name` are on the same page, I think. InDesign will never create a perfect TOC on the first shot; you *always* have to massage whatever it creates.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't need this reply anymore, but the TOC follows the order of your stories, so there is one thing that you can do, and it's:
- create a text box and write the name of the author
- create a threaded text box and write the title of the book
- place the text-box with the title before the name of the author

[image: example of the threaded text box]

P.S: The level option is helpful only when you order your entries in alphabetical order (InDesign order the entries always within their level).